# Uploading images with Multer using React Axios Nodejs but FormData with nested array of objects not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, nested, multer

I'm trying to do two things.  Save my form data in my backend with nested objects (ingredientsList) and upload two images ('cuisineImg' and 'imgUrl') with an axios post. See below setup:

```
const Create = (props) => {
    const units = ["none", "block(s)", "bushel(s)", "clove(s)", "can(s)", 
    "drop(s)", "smidgen", "pinch", "dash", "teaspoon(s)", "tablespoon(s)", 
    "fl oz(s)", "ounce(s)", "cup(s)", "pint(s)", "quart(s)", "gallon(s)", 
    "pound(s)", "milliliter(s)", "liter(s)"]


    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        title: "",
        description: "",
        ingredientsList: [
            { ingredient: "", quantity: 0, unit: units[0] },
        ],
        cuisineImg: "",
        imgUrl: "",

 const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        for (let formKey in form) {
            if (typeof (form[formKey]) === 'object') {
                for (let objectKey in form[formKey]) {
                    formData.append(`${formKey}.${objectKey}`, JSON.stringify(form[formKey][objectKey]));
                }
            }
            else {
                formData.append(i, form[i])
            }
        }

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
        }

        axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/create", formData, config)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                history.push("/")
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setErrors(err.response.data.err.errors)
            });
    }
```

There are two things wrong. One, my info is coming back like this on my backend where the req.body in [Object: null prototype], then my data.

```
req body:  [Object: null prototype] {
  title: 'Test',
  description: 'blah',
  'ingredientsList.0': '{"ingredient":"tofu","quantity":"1","unit":"block(s)"}',
  'ingredientsList.1': '{"ingredient":"onion","quantity":"2","unit":"block(s)"}',
  'imgUrl.name': '"Screen Shot 2022-04-03 at 9.19.46 AM.png"',
  'imgUrl.lastModified': '1648991991606',
  'imgUrl.lastModifiedDate': '"2022-04-03T13:19:51.606Z"',
  'imgUrl.webkitRelativePath': '""',
  'imgUrl.size': '85483',
  'imgUrl.type': '"image/png"',
  'imgUrl.arrayBuffer': 'undefined',
  'imgUrl.slice': 'undefined',
  'imgUrl.stream': 'undefined',
  'imgUrl.text': 'undefined',
}
```

Two, the images and the ingredientsList come back as iterated with numbers. I want the data to be parsed like how I have in my schema, with nested objects in one key called 'ingredientsList' with a nested object value and 'cuisineImg' is one key with a file path value, and so forth. Instead they are coming back as iterated multiple times.

And here is my route setup:

route.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
// other code removed for clarity
const upload = multer({storage: storage})

module.exports = app => {
    app.post("/api/recipes/create", upload.fields([{ name: 'cuisineImg', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'imgUrl', maxCount: 1 }]), RecipeController.createRecipe);}
```

controller.js

```
module.exports.createRecipe = (req, res) => {
    req.body.rating = 0;
    Recipe.create((req.body))
        .then(newRecipes => {
            res.json({ results: newRecipes });
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ message: "that didn't work", err }))
}
```

***Front-End Error Message:***
My front-end error shows that ingredientsList has a cast error, which I can see from how the information is being received in req.body. This is the error I see on console message:

"Recipe validation failed: ingredientsList: Cast to embedded failed for value "{"ingredient":"tofu","quantity":"1","unit":"block(s)"}" (type string) at path "ingredientsList" because of "ObjectParameterError",

***Backend:***
I tried JSON.Parse(req.body) but i get "TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value."

I'm super lost with all these moving parts. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this with Axios v0.27.2 : axios.postForm("http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/create", form) https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#-automatic-serialization

Comment: Its giving me this error after submit on front-end - "axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...).postForm is not a function". I installed axios and it should be the latest version.